# How to playfully scold someone?

Tags: usage, expressions, idioms

I haven't heard from a good friend for a while, I would like to reproach him playfully, but have no clue what the appropriate thing to say would be.

Would `恥を知れ!` be appropriate if said in a funny tone, or is it too strong of an expression?

### Edit: some context

Forgive me if I didn't add too much context, but I wanted a generic advice more than a specific one. Though I understand in language, and especially in such a language as Japanese is, it doesn't make much sense to be *context-free*.

Basically, we are very good friends, both males. We travelled a lot together while in Europe; I stayed at his place in Japan, he stayed at my place; met my family. We have a very strong connection and we are playful with eachother.

We are, however, admittetly both 筆無精. And we don't keep in touch. The reason why I wanted something more than 久しぶり is because he got married and just did an announcement on Facebook. I want to do this playful scolding, but I don't want to sound too serious: of course I really care about his life, but I understand things have been hectic and he didn't have time to contact me.

Comment: 「恥を知れ！」は、やめといた方がいいと思う・・・ww

Comment: What if you were to just use something like: "お久しぶり"?

Comment: What about `私のこと好きじゃなくなってきたの？`

Comment: @istrasci In my opinion a no-go for a male speaker. (Unless he is looking for a boyfriend...)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, as for お久しぶり, obviously I could say it. He's actually from Nagoya and I could go on and say something like 「やっとかめだがな」, but I wanted to add this *playful reproach* tone to it. As for @istrasci's suggestion, thanks! But I also feel like it would sound a bit weird as a male speaker. Anyhow, I added the context to my situation.

Comment: やっとかめだがな>>名古屋弁??

Comment: はい、そうと思う。「やっとかめ」＝とても久しぶり

Comment: @Chocolate and the famous song http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwxxtYCVOR4 though not known by many.

Comment: @oldergod www初めて聞きました

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I applaud your courage to try something new and more sophisticated, when you can so easily use some safe & mandane expressions like お久しぶり!

Unfortunately, things like this entirely depend on the context and what your perceived character is to the other person, for there's always some context in which almost any expression is appropriate.

For example, if you and he have some shared memory around that particular phrase, it'd be very much desirable to use 恥を知れ!. Or if you've been known to him as a very frank person and he had promised you to reach back to you when he didn't. I can imagine you saying something お前結婚式には呼ぶっていってたじゃんよ、奥さんに昔の恥ずかしい話をしてやろうと思ってたのに。恥を知れ（笑）.

Interestingly because the phrase itself is a pretty strong one as you note, I'd say there's actually little chance of this being taken as offensive. When you receive an e-mail like this from an old acquaintance, you just can't imagine anything that warrants such anger, so really you can only assume that he meant it lightly.

And the use of frank, straight phrases creates an intimacy and closeness, which is a good thing if you are writing to an old buddy.

If you want advices on possible other expressions, I think you need to provide a lot more context, such as whether you are a male or female, the nature of friendship, how old/young you are, etc.

Comment: Not sure if your first sentence is sarcastic: I will assume good faith, though. Thank you for your detailed answer, that is very helpful. I added the exact context in my question, so if you want you can elaborate a bit more on what you think it's more appropriate.

Comment: Also I want to add that I want to call him on the phone rather than sending him an email, so I guess I can convey playfulness without relying on assumptions on his part.

Comment: No, I didn't mean sarcastic. My bad if it comes across as such.

I'm also surprised that my example paragraph was spot on!

Comment: I must say I am slightly at loss with your example… :/

Comment: I'd say "お前結婚式には呼ぶっていってたじゃんよ、奥さんに昔の恥ずかしい話をしてやろうと思ってたのに。恥を知れ（笑）" would be "Dude, you said you'll invite me to your wedding [but you didn't!]. I was so going to tell your bride about all the stupid things you've done before you met her [but because you didn't invite me, I couldn't!] Shame on you!"

Comment: Thank you Kohsuke! :) So ultimately you think 恥を知れ could be used playfully given the right context? Do you have a preferred way to do such a thing? Like to playfully scold children and such?

Answer (score 4):

わたしなら.....

> ●ちょっとぉ～。久しぶり(orやっとかめ？)すぎるんじゃないの？ど～ゆうこと？
>   ●ナニソレ。結婚なんて聞いてなかったけど。(≒ 俺に黙って結婚するとか、アリ？)

etc...と言うかな・・・と思います。

Comment: やっぱし「恥を知れ」って冗談で言うのはちと変だね

Comment: I like your way of talking, I feel like I'm actually learning natural Japanese. Thanks